# Como deixar um botão fixo no final do LinearLayout via código (sem usar xml)?

Tags: android

Tenho um linearLayout, e coloquei ele como `MATCHPARENT` para ocupar toda a tela do tablet, porém eu precisava deixar um botão fixo no final da tela. Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Com xml é fácil, porém via Java não estou conseguindo. Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Coloque a gravidade, utilizando `setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)`.

Comment: Segue o link da documentação do `Gravity`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html.